# Implementing Send for a pointer wrapper

Tags: pointers, rust, send

I'm trying to understand exactly when I can have a type implement `Send`, and this isn't very clear from the [Rust nomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/send-and-sync.html).

Specifically, I have a builder struct (say `Builder`) that contains a `Vec<*mut std::os::raw::c_char>`:

```rust
pub struct Builder{
    list: Vec<*mut std::os::raw::c_char>,
}
```

These pointers actually come from a destructured `std::ffi::CString` (by using `std::ffi::CString::into_raw`).   Hence, these pointers are actually *owned* by the builder (in the sense that I manually implement `Drop` for `Builder` and reconstitute the `std::ffi::CString` to free the memory), but they have to be stored in this manner due to FFI requirements.

This builder type is not `Copy` and not `Clone`, so there will never be a situation where I end up with multiple builders thinking that they own the same char pointers.  These pointers are also never exposed directly in the builder's public API.

Of course, since pointers are `!Send` and `Vec` of `!Send` is also `!Send`, `Builder` is `!Send` by default.  However, it would appear to me, since my builder semantically maintains ownership of the pointers, that it is safe to manually implement `Send` for `Builder`.  I believe what I'm doing is similar to manually implementing a `Box`, and [`Box` is `Send` if the thing inside the box is also `Send`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#impl-Send), just that in my case, the thing inside the "box" is logically a slice (`[const std::os::raw::c_char]`, which is `Send`) instead of a raw pointer (`*mut const std::os::raw::c_char`, which is `!Send`).

Is this indeed the case (and is my understanding of `Send` correct), and is there anything else I should worry about when implementing `Send` for `Builder`?

Comment: Pointers are `!Send` because they might point to shared data that is not safe to access from multiple threads. One lithmus test for `Send` safety is is it safe to drop the value in a thread different than the one where it was created? A type that uses a thread-local allocator would fail that test.

Comment: `Rc` would fail that test as well, but for a different reason: its `Drop` decreases the reference count that is shared by all clones of the  `Rc`, and does so without synchronization. Dropping two clones of the same `Rc` in two different threads would constitute a data race. (`Rc` also modifies its control block from `clone()` which takes a shared reference, but that just means that it can't be `Sync`.)

Comment: @user4815162342 Yes, but none of those cases apply here, since [`std::ffi::CString`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.CString.html) is `Send`.  Perhaps the question boils down to whether you can destructure a `CString` in one thread and reconstitute it in another.

Comment: *Yes, but none of those cases apply here* - then it's safe to `impl Send` for your wrapper. (My comment was not meant to imply that it's unsafe for you to `impl Send`, but  to provide general guidelines for when it might be unsound to do so.) Not implementing `Send` by default for pointers forces you to think about the guarantees. And destructuring a `CString` can certainly be done in another thread, as that operation doesn't really do anything to the allocated data, it just affects Rust's view of its compile-time ownership.